# Hive Udf for TOP funtion

Tags: hive, hive-udf

We are joining tables from hana and hive and a view creating query from Smart Data Access

```
EX: Select top 10 from hana.table join hive.table
```

Hana support TOP funtion but Hive doesnt. Is there any existing UDF present in Hive similar to TOP. I know in hive we have LIMIT but we required a UDF function which similar to hana?

Please suggest any workaround for this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use the [LIMIT](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Select#LanguageManualSelect-LIMITClause) function

Comment: As Hana view creating top so we required TOP function in hive.